# Different result: selection per script <> about GMail Menu

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am trying to write a simple script to get a count from all my emails in GMail:

```
function myFunction(){
var c = 0;
var threads = GmailApp.search('in:all');
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var c = c + threads[i].getMessages().length;
}
Logger.log(c);
}
```

With this script I get the result of 207, but when I click on the GMail-Menu  "All Mail" U get the result of 173.

[image]
[image]

When I change the filter in the script from "in:all" to "in:inbox" or "in:trash" or "in:sent", the count matches between my script and the Gmail user interface. It seem that only the "in:all" filter produces a different count.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there a point I over looked?

Comment: Can you try change in:all to in:anywhere? in:all search filter is nowhere to be found in the official [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Comment: Hello, the same problem.